# Button group issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page that uses Bootstrap 3 that looks like:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Test</button></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Test <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2ja6/)

As you can see, the page is screwed up (the button group is on two lines). But when I take out the link around the button, it looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using only links

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default">Test</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Test <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X2ja6/2/)